# Maven - Can I reference profile id in profile definition?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I've set profiles in a `pom.xml`, like shown as follows:

```
<profile>
<id><em>profileId1</em></id>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/<em>profileId1</em>.properties</filter>
        </filters>
// rest of the profile 
</profile>
<profile>
<id><em>profileId2</em></id>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/<em>profileId2</em>.properties</filter>
        </filters>
// rest of the profile
</profile>
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to extract this piece from all the profiles, so that there is no need to repeat it for every profile (and possibly misspell it)?

Answer (score 41):

With maven 2.2.1 and later, I was able to get the ID of the first active profile using:

```
${project.activeProfiles[0].id}
```

Of course this fails if there is not a least one active profile.

Using the

```
${project.profiles[0].id}
```

as suggested by Pascal did **not** work for me.

Hint: While investigating this, I really started to love `mvn help:evaluate`.

Comment: Using `${project.activeProfiles[0].id}` worked perfectly for me. You can make sure at least one profile will be active with `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` in one profile's activation block.

Comment: Same here, ${project.activeProfiles[0].id} worked, maven 3.2

Comment: For some reason, it won't extract a parent pom property; so if, for instance, you activate 2 profiles, one being from a parent, only the current project property will be retrieved.

Comment: If there's multiple profiles active, this looks like `activeProfiles[0].id` could to the wrong id.

Comment: @antak It uses the order of the profiles as listed in the pom.xml

Comment: Is something like that for active execution id ?

Answer (score 19):

As an alternative to `${project.activeProfiles[0].id}` (which doesn't seem to work on older versions of maven), just define a property:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <profile-id>dev</profile-id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Then use `${profile-id}`.

Note: just make sure one is always active by default

Comment: Why do i see a snake biting its tail?

Answer (score 4):

According to [PLXUTILS-37](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXUTILS-37), it should be possible to access properties in a List or Map using "Reflection Properties" (see the [MavenPropertiesGuide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) for more about this).

So just try `${project.profiles[0].id}`, `${project.profiles[1].id}`, etc.

If this doesn't work (I didn't check if it does), I'd use profile activation based on a system property as described in [Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and use that property in the filter. Something like that:

```
<profile>  
  <id>profile-profileId1</id>  
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>profile</name>
      <value>profileId1</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>  
    <filters>  
      <filter>src/main/filters/${profile}.properties</filter>  
    </filters>  
    // rest of the profile  
</profile>
```

To activate this profile, you would type this on the command line:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -Dprofile=profileId1
```