# Include Maven profile name in assembly-plugin built (with dependencies) jar

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin to build an executable, monolithic jar with dependencies.  I'm also using resource filtering to set some custom, lane-specific (dev, stage, prod, etc) properties.

How do I make the finalName of the jar include the lane name (dev, stage, prod, etc)?

I'd like the following mvn commands to result in jars that look something like this:

- mvn clean install -P DEV   --> ws-client-DEV.jar
- mvn clean install -P STAGE --> ws-client-STAGE.jar
- mvn clean install -P PROD  --> ws-client-PROD.jar

Is there a maven property somewhere I can't find?  I would like to avoid using a redundant command line argument if possible (ie - 'mvn clean install -P DEV -Dlane=DEV').

Here's my assembly plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>ws-client</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>Example</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to Bhaskar's but slightly modified.

After the <build> tag, add

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${lane}</finalName>
```

You can set the lane value as a property in the profile.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>DEV</id>
        <properties>
            <lane>DEV</lane>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then execute the build like you say:
mvn ... -P DEV (e.g. mvn clean install -P DEV)

Comment: The finalName will not work on the deployed artifact only on the artifact which is stored in the target folder in your current run.

Comment: @khmarbaise - Correct.  For this particular usage, the jar is being distributed outside of a repository (I know, not ideal).  I wanted a visual indication so that the "mavenless" consumer knows what lane and properties they're using by simply glancing at the jar file on their classpath.

Comment: How to add the -1.0-SNAPSHOT suffix to the custom name ?

Comment: @StephaneEybert use `-${project.version}`

Answer (score 3):

After the <build> tag, add

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${lane}</finalName>
```

And set the "lane" env variable to the profile name e.g.

mvn -P DEV -Dlane=DEV etc.

Or you can be a bit more creative and discover the active profile ID as described here [Maven - Can I reference profile id in profile definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012198/maven-can-i-reference-profile-id-in-profile-definition)

EDIT ------

If you want to avoid redundant arguments.

Why not trigger the corresponding profiles by using the env. property.

so on command line

```
mvn -Dlane=DEV|STAGE|PROD
```

and in the pom

```
<profile>  
  <id>DEV</id>  
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>lane</name>
      <value>DEV</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>  
    // rest of the profile  
</profile>
```

And same for STAGE and PROD profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I wanted to avoid using a redundant command line argument if possible (I've updated my question to reflect that).  Your provided link is interesting.  Any ideas on how to reference the command line specified (active) profile via a mvn property?

Comment: Edited with more info about avoiding redunduncy