# How to get (access) active profile name(s) in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

- Is there a way to get the active profile name or id from the pom.xml.
- I found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012198/maven-can-i-reference-profile-id-in-profile-definition), which suggest the `${project.profiles[0].id}`, `${project.profiles[1].id}` But it is not working on apache-maven-3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use help plugin:

```
$ mvn help:active-profiles
```

It will list all active profiles for the project for you.

Comment: I need to access that within the pom file as a property. (ex: `${project.build.finalName}` )

Comment: Using ${project.activeProfiles[0].id} does not solve the issue ?

Comment: What is your purpose of getting it inside pom.xml ? Maybe check if your architecture and profile usage is adequate: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Help-referencing-profile-properties-attributes-td3349143.html