# How to get current maven profile Id in java

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium webdriver with maven and struggling. I have a set of maven profiles

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>demo</id>
            <properties/>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties/>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

My task is quite simple but i can't find a solution. How can i get and store into variable id of the current profile after i call for example `mvn test -P prod`? This id is needed later in tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - Can I reference profile id in profile definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012198/maven-can-i-reference-profile-id-in-profile-definition)

Comment: did i understand correctly when i start maven with chosen profile **-P demo** for instance. It's stored in activeProperties list? I still don't understand how do i initialize variable from code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this solution:
First add property to your profile i.e.

```
  <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
         <properties>prod<properties>
   </profile>
```

Than create properties file app.properties with entry

mvnprod=${prod}

read the property file in your code.

Comment: read the property file only gets the '${prod}' string itself。not the parsed variable. I already turned on filtering on <resources>.

Comment: and I changed `<properties>prod<properties>` to `<properties><prod>prod</prod></properties>`

Comment: Hi, can you check my question